# Mod rewrite, need to allow only letters, numbers and white spaces

Tags: url-rewriting, lighttpd

Since I need to allow my users, to search strings with white spaces, I need to modify this rewrite rule (lighttpd engine).

```
"^/(results)/(query)/([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)$" => "index.php?action=results&query=$3",
```

To allow only letters, numbers and white spaces (I guess only those are needed to search some data from MySQL?).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whitespace in regex is `\s`

```
"^/(results)/(query)/([0-9a-zA-Z_\s]+)$" => "index.php?action=results&query=$3"
```

or

```
"^/(results)/(query)/([\w\d\s_]+)$" => "index.php?action=results&query=$3"
```

If `-` sign needed, it must be the first in range

```
"^/(results)/(query)/([-0-9a-zA-Z_\s]+)$" => "index.php?action=results&query=$3"
```

See the basics on [lighttpd wiki](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs%3aModRewrite) and complete regex [reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).